# WPF - ObservableCollection casting

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method named 'PersonsMeeting' that gets as parameter ObservableCollection of Person. Can I somehow deliver it an ObservableCollection of Employee ? what casting do I need ?

p.s - I don't want to get rid of the ObservableCollection type in the method since I'm using it's functionality.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Emp { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Emp = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        InitializeComponent();
        PersonsMeeting(Emp); // How Do I Cast this ?!?!?!??
    }

    private void PersonsMeeting(ObservableCollection<Person> persons)
    {
        // ....
    }
}

public class Person{}
public class Employee : Person{}
```

Comment: if you do not need functionality of ObservableCollection<T> in your PersonsMeeting function, maybe you could use a more generic interface for your prototype like IList<Person> or even IEnumerable<Person>.

Comment: @Joachim Kerschbaumer - unfortunately I do need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know that every Employee is a Person, you can simply use [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) to cast the elements to the type needed:

<strike>PersonsMeeting(Emp.Cast());</strike>

```
PersonsMeeting(new ObservableCollection<Person>(Emp.Cast<Person>()));
```

But this will most likely not produce the results you expect since you're really creating a new ObservableCollection rather than utilizing the existing one.

**Update 2**

I notice that the PersonsMeeting method is private and that you're only ever calling it with an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`.

If that's the case, then you're trying to use an unnecessary abstraction in your private method. You can safely get rid of that and simply modify `PersonsMeeting` to take an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`.

The other option is to change the way your class is exposing its data. If you want to keep the abstraction, make your class look like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> _readOnlyEmp = null;
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _emp = new ObservableCollection<Person>;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person> Emp
    {
        if(_readOnlyEmp = null)
            _readOnlyEmp = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Person>(_emp);

        return _readOnlyEmp;
    }

    public void AddEmployee(Employee e)
    {
        _emp.Add(e);
    }

    public void RemoveEmployee(Employee e)
    { 
        _emp.Remove(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but after doing what you've suggested I'm getting compilation errors:
The best overloaded method match for 'WpfApplication1.MainWindow.PersonsMeeting(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.Person>)' has some invalid arguments

----------

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WpfApplication1.Person>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.Person>'

Comment: @Erez - Correct. That's a mistake on my part reading your code. What portion of the ObservableCollection functionality do you need inside of PersonsMeeting?

Comment: I need the collection to notify that it changed (items been remvoed/add).

Comment: @Erez - I just posted a bunch of updates...hopefully something makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
PersonsMeeting(Emp.OfType<Person>);
```

or

```
PersonsMeeting(Emp.Cast<Person>);
```

Comment: thanks but not passing compilation , see my comments to 
Justin Niessner

Comment: if `PersonsMeeting` takes an `ObservableCollection` as parameter, using any of your methods will fail as you wont have an `ObservableCollection` after calling `OfType<Person>` or `Cast<Person>`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind generics:

```
private void PersonsMeeting<T>(ObservableCollection<T> persons) where T: Person
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the class should be ObservableCollection, try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        var persons = employees.OfType<Person>();

        Test(new ObservableCollection<Person>(persons));
    }

    static void Test(ObservableCollection<Person> persons)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Person { }
public class Employee : Person { }
```

Comment: In addition, there are certain behaviors of classes that could break generic covariance/contravariance even in .NET 4.0 (it's tricky).

Comment: Cant do that, I need it as ObservableCollection